# Script loads a function before I call it locally but publicly it loads it after

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onclicklistener

Sorry for the confusing title, but my sidenav on my [portfolio website](https://me.insanewolfhd.com/) opens when I run the html page. When I use it on my website, it just says `Uncaught ReferenceError: openNav is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):23) onclick @ (index):23` which just leads me to where I'm calling the function. Is it because I'm loading the script after I call it? How come it works locally though?

Also I have my server going through Cloudflare if that's any help. I've also already tried uploading my local files and replacing the ones on the server completely, they were the exact same though.

One more also, I have the page on Github Pages as well and it works fine.
[Github Pages](https://insanewolfhd2.github.io/portfolio/index.html)

**EDIT:** Relevent Code?:

```js
$(function(){$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();});$('.tool-tip').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});const openNav=()=>{if($(window).width()>2000){document.getElementById("mySideNav").style.width="750px";}else{document.getElementById("mySideNav").style.width="250px";}
document.getElementById("navTextWrapper").style.display="block";}
const closeNav=()=>{document.getElementById("mySideNav").style.width="0";document.getElementById("navTextWrapper").style.display="none";}
```

```html
<span class="openMenu" onclick="openNav();">&#9776;</span>
<nav id="mySideNav" class="sidenav">
<div id="navTextWrapper">
<div class="navBrandExit">
<a href="#" class="brand">Kenneth Rhodes</a><a href="#" class="closeBtn" onclick="event.preventDefault(); closeNav();">&times;</a>
</div>
<a href="#showcase">Top</a>
<a href="#perks">Skills</a>
<a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code directly into your question?

Comment: @samanime I think that should be what you're looking for, though a better example of it would probably be on the site...

Comment: Are you sure `js/main.js` is loading? Also, perhaps consider using jquery for click handlers rather than the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: @csum Well main.js wasn't loading properly due to rocket loader (Lucas's answer) but thank you for the recommendation, I might implement that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your website it seems js/main.js is not being loaded properly, can you try turning off Rocket Loader in cloudflare Performance Settings to see if it has any impact? You can get to your Performance Settings by going to:

Speed > Rocket loader

Comment: Wow, that was the problem, thank you! What can I do to use rocket loader and get rid of this problem though? Rocket loader helps my page speed only slightly but now this means I can't use it site-wide.

Comment: Thanks for choosing my answer, maybe you can disable rocket loader for some of your scripts? https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436--How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-Automatic-Mode-

Comment: Or just disable it entirely ;)

Comment: No problem, you deserve the rep. But I don't know, doesn't Rocket Loader have a significant impact on performance? Edit: Yeah you're right, I could just disable it for that script. Thanks for the link :).